# How to forcefully cause compilation error of debugging code only for the build release?

Tags: android, debugging, compiler-errors

When I develop app, I frequently add some bits of code for debugging/dev-t purposes. Unfortunately, I also tend to forget these bits of code, when I create release APK. I would like to use some solution to invoke compilation error only for release build.

Any well-known solution or some new idea for that? This would be the best *forgetfulness-proofing* my development :)

Answer (score 0):

You can user variables from `BuildConfig` such as `Debug` (returns boolean) or `FLAVOR` if you would like to throw error for different flavor value.

Better solution is to place your DEBUG code in structure like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
  //place your debug code here
}
```

And you will do not need to remove it.
If you still need to throw information in non debug build to remove that just check if `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is false and throw an exception.

Comment: I was actually asking about compilation error, not runtime exception. But thanks anyway.